# Big html blur doesn't work on firefox and has a slow performance on Safari

Tags: html, css, performance, firefox, safari

I have these Shapes on my Website as a background, so they need to be extremely blurred:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<div class="absolute w-[80rem] h-[80rem] -left-72 top-[32rem] bg-blue-800 blur-[100px] opacity-40 rounded-full"></div>
<div class="absolute w-[50rem] h-[50rem] left-[50rem] top-0 bg-pink-900 blur-[100px] opacity-40 rounded-full"></div>
```

On firefox, the blur just can't be bigger than 100px, and on safari, the performance is awful and laggy.

Is there another way to add that gradient effect to my website or what else can I do?

Comment: What are you blurring? Your example is just a coloured, where the blur is so big you might as well start looking into [radial gradients](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gradient/radial-gradient). Is your example really representative of the problem you are trying to solve? If not, please pick a more representative example.

Comment: I don't seem to be able to reproduce your problem - the FF and Edge/Chrome versions look pretty similar. Could you perhaps add some pictures so we can see what you are seeing?